# Allow only one button to be clicked at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a form with different button options. I want the user to only be allowed to select one button. Basically I have 6 of these buttons inside of the form and when you click it the button color changes to green and says selected. Right now I can select all of the button options, I want it to where when I click one of the buttons if I click another one, then the first one I selected gets "unchecked"

```
   <button type="button" class="button-school" value="hidden-springs">
              <h2>Hidden Springs</h2>
              <span class="select-active">SELECT</span>
   </button>
```

I only posted one of the buttons but they are all the same with different values and h2 values. I was trying to find something online to help me but I was really only seeing things for radio buttons, this one is one that I made myself.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
jQuery('.button-school').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace('SELECT', 'SELECTED'));
  } else {
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace('SELECTED', 'SELECT'));
  }
});

</script>
```

I see stuff about "if clicked" can I do something where I can only have one "active"?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: give some example....

Comment: @Paulie_D  I posted what I have so far

Comment: Added a shorter solution, *to the problem shown*, but I would generally recommend you do not depend on content (like you do with the string replacements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.button-school').click(function() {
    $('.button-school').not(this).removeClass('active').html(function() {
      return $(this).html().replace('SELECTED', 'SELECT');
    });
    $(this).addClass('active').html(jQuery(this).html().replace('SELECT', 'SELECTED'));
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/v2ddpuw6/2/

### Notes:

- `jQuery(function(){})` is a shortcut for a DOM ready handler, which also passed itself as the first parameter. This way you can avoid loads of `jQuery` and use `$` safely.
- If you use `html()` with a function, the return value is used to replace the existing `html`.
- You can exclude the current selection from all matches with `not()` to filter all except the clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use ***both*** buttons ***and*** radio buttons

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
<button type="button" class="cstm-rad" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">Custom Radio Button</button>
```

CSS selecting, style the button based on whether or not it's preceded by a `:checked` item:
`button.cstm-rad{ /*inactive style*/ }`
`:checked + button.cstm-rad{ /*active style*/ }`

EDIT NOTE: This is almost exactly the same solution I submitted originally, just cleaned of superfluous text, more CSS, and given non-terrible naming conventions.

Comment: Yes, downvote the native solution for no given reason! You're just mad I had the gall, nay, the *understanding* of how to do it without jQ.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a really crude way of implementing this, but basically you have it so when one of the submit buttons are clicked it will then hide all of the submit buttons so the user can no longer click on them.

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v2ddpuw6/

Html

```
<input type="button" value="Submit1" class="Submit"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit2" class="Submit"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit3" class="Submit"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit4" class="Submit"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit5" class="Submit"/>
```

jQuery

```
$(function()
{
    $('.Submit').on('click', function()
  {
    $('.Submit').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Firstly, calling them submit buttons is a bad idea, since that's semantically mapped to `type=submit` buttons which submit the form. Secondly... Why.... Why use jQuery here? It's so trivial to do this in normal Javascript. as;dlkugboaih;lsdkjfasdjaklgj

Comment: the OP has tagged jQuery so i don't see a problem, also I did state this was a `crude` way. the OP hasn't provided any example code

Comment: @Canvas I tried your code and implemented it to work for me, however when I click on a button they all disappear "hide" I don't want them to hide when I click one. Hope you understand what I mean

Comment: @Canvas Yea yea, it was tagged.... I still think any time it's trivial to do with pure Javascript, you should, regardless. jQuery is just... *shudder*. As for crude, still doesn't justify calling them submits. I'll fix that one and suggest the edit since I'm so triggered by it =P

Comment: @abluejelly: properly written the jQuery equivalent will usually be shorter than raw JS *and* you get more features from the jQuery event model than you do from the browser equivalent. If you update your own answer *to do the equivalent* we can make that decision ourselves :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie But that wasn't what the question asked for. The question wanted to use `<button>` tags to emulate `<input type="radio" />` tags, hence my answer. And while hiding all of them would be "larger" in pure JS, you could always just shim in the part of jQ you wanted (the "bind all to this function" call) with something like: `function $$bind(grp, o) { for (var i = grp.length >>> 0; i--;) { $.bind(grp[i], o); } }` and simply pass a document.querySelectorAll(); call to it. Your jQuery is only "shorter" because all of its bloat is in that jQuery library you included.

Comment: Sorry forgot I called another function I wrote. Not enough space to include it within the character limit, so it's here:
`$.bind = function (ele, o) { for (var event in o) ele.addEventListener(event, o[event]); };`

Comment: @abluejelly: The green tick would indicate I understood the question *well enough*. Using a term like "bloat" for a library like jQuery is emotive and misguided. The size of jQuery would only matter if you only write a few lines of client-side code. Most sites have it cached via a CDN so it is already available *if you want it* :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Your answer doesn't do what this answer does, which is the one I was chiding for using jQ for such a simple task and claiming didn't do what the question asked for. I also had already provided a native solution before getting into this argument. So I'm really not sure what you're getting on about now.

Answer (score 0):

i have check your code and got the issue. Here is the working example what you are looking for.

Please check here is the code.

```js
jQuery('.button-school').click(function() {
  
  if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery('.button-school').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.button-school').html(jQuery('.button-school').html().replace('SELECTED', 'SELECT'));
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace('SELECT', 'SELECTED'));
  } else {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace('SELECTED', 'SELECT'));
  }
});
```

```css
.active{ 
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="button-school" value="hidden-springs">
              <h2>Hidden Springs</h2>
              <span class="select-active">SELECT</span>
   </button>

<button type="button" class="button-school" value="hidden-springs">
              <h2>Hidden Springs</h2>
              <span class="select-active">SELECT</span>
   </button>

<button type="button" class="button-school" value="hidden-springs">
              <h2>Hidden Springs</h2>
              <span class="select-active">SELECT</span>
   </button>
```

Enjoy !!!!!!!!!!!